# Floating divs not aligning the way I want them

Tags: css, css-float

A very simple css question. I have a page where I want my blocks to float nicely:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 620px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 300px; background-color: Red; height: 230px;"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 300px; background-color: Blue; height: 330px;"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 300px; background-color: Green; height: 230px;"></div></div>
```

I would like the green div to be display just under the red div and not aligned with the end of the blue div.

Changing the order is not a solution for me as they are coming in a specific order from the DB.

Regards
Jonas

Comment: A Very simple question. Where is your Code?

Comment: Where are your `green div` `red div` `blue div`?

Comment: Please add your code. -1.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/WsgSV/) what you are looking for? I changed the Blue `div` to `float:right`

Comment: Colored <div>s that "are coming in a specific order from the DB"? o_O

Comment: Sorry about the missing code, I am new here :)
Thanks, Yes that is the I would like it to look, but as I said, I get the blobks from my database and there are many (Aorund 70 ), so not easy to determine what should float left and what should float right.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="float: left; width: 620px;">
    <div style="float: left; clear: left; width: 300px; background-color: Red; height: 230px;"></div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 300px; background-color: Blue; height: 330px;"></div>
    <div style="float: left;  clear: left; width: 300px; background-color: Green; height: 230px;"></div>
</div>
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/xMsH5/).

Comment: This just puts the 3 divs beneath each other. I want to use two colunms if they fit. (red and green in left column and blue in right column, but dont want the space between red and green )

Comment: Thanks, Yes that is the I would like it to look, but as I said, I get the blocks from my database and there are many (Aorund 70 ), so not easy to determine what should float left and what should float right.
The hight vary from 50px to 500px

Comment: I think we'll need some more information on the full problem you're working on. Are there three divs (red, green and blue) or an unknown number (up to 70)? If there are more than three, how do you want them arranged?

Comment: Yes it is an Unknown number. (Maybe even more than 70 going forward) 
It is "poster notes" all with a datestamp at the top when they were posted. Similar to the wall on google+ 
Want arranged left to right and then down ( rather avoid white space than stricly enforce the date order

Comment: If you have no control over the markup then that's a surprisingly tricky feat in CSS. You may want to check out something like isotope to handle the layout: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html

Comment: @doctororange: I agree on that above post. It is difficult to do when there is no control over the number of div's and which would be of what size.

Comment: Thanks, looks nice.
Will for now alternate between float left and float right, and see what my client says to tha.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly, the below is what you need.

I changed the Blue `div` to `float: right` so that the Green `div` comes just under the Red `div`.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 620px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 300px; background-color: Red; height: 230px;"></div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 300px; background-color: Blue; height: 330px;"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 300px; background-color: Green; height: 230px;"></div>
</div>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WsgSV/)

Comment: Thanks, Yes that is the I would like it to look, but as I said, I get the blobks from my database and there are many (Aorund 70 ), so not easy to determine what should float left and what should float right.

Comment: @JonasMandahlPedersen: Yes, that is true. I will let you know if I find any other alternates. (There are many better brains in SO too :)) As a side note, I would recommend keeping styles (CSS) and HTML code separate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="clear:left;float: left; width: 300px; background-color: Green; height: 230px;"></div>
```

or

```
<br><div style="float: left; width: 300px; background-color: Green; height: 230px;"></div>
```

or

```
<div style="float: left; width: 330px;">
```

It's up to you.